# tcpdump(pcap-filters) для отлова ICMP пакетов заданного размера

Tags: linux, сеть, wireshark, tcpdump

Пытаюсь заснифать определенный тип ping запроса(ping размером N байт) с помощью tsharsk.
На удаленной машине запущен

```
ping 192.168.201.69 -s 30
```

На машине ловлю tshark

```
./tshark -i 3 -T json -c 10  -f "ether host <MAC удаленной машины> and icmp"
```

Не понимаю как указать поле **icmp.data.datalen** == 30
Изучение манов, меня не просветляет. Везде в примерах фигурирует использование синтаксиса icmp[icmptype], но где посмотреть все доступные поля я не нашел.

UPDATE

Судя по [ману](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter)

> The following ICMP type field values are available: icmp-echoreply, icmp-unreach, icmp-sourcequench, icmp-redirect, icmp-echo, icmp-routeradvert, icmp-routersolicit, icmp-timxceed, icmp-paramprob, icmp-tstamp, icmp-tstampreply, icmp-ireq, icmp-ireqreply, icmp-maskreq, icmp-maskreply.

в capture фильтр нельзя задать ICMP.data.len. Но может я что-то не верно понял.

Comment: Для линукс это, tshark -f icmp и далее

Comment: как вариант, можно смотреть длину ip, она на 28 байт больше для ipv4 icmp-echo-*-пакетов: `icmp && ip.len == 58`

Comment: @Fat-Zer я думаю ваш коммент можно засчитать как решение.